# Declaring a function in a header file which references structs defined in different header files

Tags: c

Suppose we have three C files with corresponding header files: `file1.c`, `file1.h`, `file2.c`, `file2.h`, `file3.c`, and `file3.h`.

In `file1.c`, we define `func1()` using `struct1`, and define the `struct1` and declare `func1()` in `file1.h`.

In `file2.c`, we define `func2()` using `struct2`, and define the `struct2` and declare `func2()` in `file2.h`.

Then, we can define a `func3()` in `file3.c` that uses both `struct1` and `struct2` by including `file1.h` and `file2.h` in `file3.c`. But how do I declare `func3()` in `file3.h`?

Comment: Please don't confuse us. Break down your query, kindly.

Comment: Learn how to format first form [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include `file1.h` and `file2.h` in `file3.h` instead of `file3.c`. As `func3` uses `struct1` and `struct2`, you can't declare it without having the declarations of the structs on hand. Don't be tempted to redeclare the structs in `file3.h`.